# a question about the Turing machine

Tags: turing-machines

Can a Turing machine turn the operation "addition" into "multiplication"?

This is a question proposed by one of my classmates. And my teacher told me "no" without any explanation. So does anybody have any idea about it?

Comment: What do you mean with "turn into" in this context ?

Comment: What would it _mean_ for a TM to turn addition into multiplication?